# Check user authentication In Php/symfony

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, jwt

I have a Doubt on authentication. 
There are a lot of methods of auth ( JWT, cookies, Session ), my question is very simple, anytime that user requests a new resource, the Client send something towards server ( for example Jwt in header), but Where I have to place the code to check Jwt or cookie or session? If I Use PHP, without MVC, I have to include any time the class or call some static method? And in Symfony I have to use Events ?

Comment: Typically, it'd be handled by something called middleware.

Comment: @ceejayoz exactly, I use node with express and I use app.use to check JWT, but How can I do in php and Symfony ?

Comment: You can do middleware in PHP/Symfony. For Symfony, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html. For your own PHP, you'd have to build a solution.

Comment: The actual implementation very much depends on your actual use case and the Symfony version you use. Can you explain your circumstances a bit more?

Comment: @xabbuh my Question is general, but in this moment I'm using Symfony 3

Comment: In Symfony 3 I recommend you to look into the new Guard component which makes handling authentication much easier (see http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-guard-authentication-component and https://knpuniversity.com/blog/guard-authentication). When it comes to authorisation, you should read about [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html). There is also an [ACL component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html), but you don't need it in 99% of the common use cases.

Comment: @xabbuh thanks a lot, I want to understand How it works under the hood, What happen for each request ? when Symfony / php call the "check" ? How detect when user is not auth ?

Comment: @monkeyUser Have you considered reading the documentation you're being linked to?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes And thanks you, But I don't understand where place these controls

Answer (score 1):

To provide default authentication in symfony2/3 you can use this guide http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html

Also there available bundle with some functional for registration/authorization: FOSUserBundle

There is a example how to implement custom authentication provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Sorry I don't have many reputation for post more than 2 links...

Comment: thanks, but each Request through these function? How it works under the hood?

Comment: In standard symfony app each request goes through all Registered onKernelRequest event listeners and subscribers. I don't know better way how to organise it in Symfony2. I'm using custom providers for token-based authentication for REST API. But you don't need to manualy check it on each request symfony will do it for you. All that you need to do it's just create ACL in security.yml or use @Security annotations from FrameworkExtraBundle.